# Access I cannot manually add a record to a table:

Tags: ms-access, indexing, vba, primary-key

Adding a record to tblCompany fails with VBA (error code 3022), and I cannot add a new record manually into the table either.

When I try to add a record to the table using vba (with rs, .addnew, ..., .update), .update gives error 3022:

> "The changes you requested to the table were not succesful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship"

tblCompany contains as PK: CompanyID (Autonumber)

I tried to open the table and manually add a record. I get the same error message, without error code.

What I tried so far:

- I created a new database with just one table and I can add records normally (I could not reproduce this error)
- My database is compacted and repaired, there is still the problem
- I open a backup from few days ago, with no such error. I haven't edited relationships between tables since then.
- I tried to import tblCompanies from my backup (remove relationships and erase the table from my current database, and import the same table with same name), and the problem is still there.
- I tried a fix from support.microsoft.com which I can apply, but the problem is still there:

code tried:

```
iMaxID = DMax("<AutonumberFieldName>", "<TableName>") + 1
sqlFixID = "ALTER TABLE <TableName> ALTER COLUMN <AutonumberFieldName> COUNTER(" & <iMaxID> & ",1)"
enter code here
```

Note: I noticed in my working backup, PK CompanyID is not indexed. In the current version it is now Indexed: Yes(no duplicates) and I cannot select Indexed: No again.

What should I do?

Here is the exact piece of code I use. Context: I update my database from an SAP extract and I show a progress bar. I update tables Article, Company, Purchase Orders. This extract is from the subroutine which updates tblCompany. If a new company (SupplierSapID) is found I create a new record in tblCompany. Note: tblCompany PK is CompanyID: autonumber. I do not set its value between .addnew and .update.

```
    Set db = CurrentDb
    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT SupplierSapID FROM tbl6SapImport ;"
    Set rsSupplierSList = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    Set rsSupplier = db.OpenRecordset("tbl1Companies", dbOpenDynaset)

    If Not (rsSupplierSList.EOF And rsSupplierSList.BOF) Then
    rsSupplierSList.MoveFirst
    Do Until rsSupplierSList.EOF = True 'we loop through the shortlist
        CurrentItem = CurrentItem + 1
        OverallItem = OverallItem + 1
        Call Form_frmProgressBarDouble.UpdateProgressBarDouble("Updating Database", CurrentItem, TotalNumberOfRecordsCurrent, "Task 3/5: Updating Company table", OverallItem, TotalNumberOfRecordsOverall)
        rsSupplier.FindFirst "CompanySapID = " & rsSupplierSList("SupplierSapID")
        If rsSupplier.NoMatch = True Then 'we need to add the supplier
            With rsSupplier
                sql = "SELECT tbl6SapImport.SupplierName, tbl6SapImport.SupplierSapID FROM tbl6SapImport WHERE tbl6SapImport.SupplierSapID = '" & rsSupplierSList("SupplierSapID") & "' ; "
                Set rsTmp = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)
                .AddNew
                !CompanySapID = rsTmp("SupplierSapID")
                !CompanyName = rsTmp("SupplierName")
                addedSuppliers = addedSuppliers & rsTmp("SupplierSapID") & ";"
                .Update
            End With
        End If
        rsSupplierSList.MoveNext
    Loop
    End If
```

Note: When I open a backup in which I still can manualy add records in tblCompanies, if I compact and repair it, then I cannot add records anymore, with described error.

Comment: Please share the code you're using to add that record. Avoid setting autonumbers for new records, they set themselves to the correct value.

Comment: Eric, I added the code. Thank you for looking into my problem.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-40.html